# I2C on explorer 16 board not working

Tags: pic, i2c, oscilloscope

I am using the Explorer 16 Board for building a Accel connected by I2C .
Currently I have only the I2C part done and I am trying to tap scl1 & sda1 using oscilloscope. The accel has to connected yet to the the MCU!

But on oscilloscope I dont see any signals on both SCl1,SDA1, any help ? here is the code :

```
UINT config1 = 0,i=0;
UINT config2 = 0;

/* Turn off I2C modules */
CloseI2C1();    //Disbale I2C1 mdolue if enabled previously

ConfigIntI2C1(MI2C_INT_OFF);  //Disable I2C interrupt

config1 = (I2C_ON  | I2C_7BIT_ADD );
config2 = 157;
OpenI2C3(config1,config2);   //configure I2C1

IdleI2C1();
StartI2C1();
while(I2C1CONbits.SEN );  //Wait till Start sequence is completed
MI2C1_Clear_Intr_Status_Bit;
```

Comment: Usually microcontrollers have pin multiplexing between GPIO and module functionality. Perhaps you have to change those settings so that the I2C module is what the pins are configured for.

Comment: Which PIM are you using with your Explorer 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `OpenI2Cx()` says that it configures the I2C control register and the I2C baud rate generator. You still need to set up the GPIO lines themselves.

What I did in my PIC24 I2C application is:

- Configure PPS (may not be necessary for you)
- Disable ADC on the I2C lines
- Set the TRIS registers on the I2C lines as inputs